# Passing variables between host and device in CUDA

Tags: c, cuda

I've the following CUDA kernel, that does a Breadth First Search.

```
__global__ void bfs(const Edge* edges, int* vertices, int* current_depth, bool* done){

    int e = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int vfirst = edges[e].first;
    int dfirst = vertices[vfirst];
    int vsecond = edges[e].second;
    int dsecond = vertices[vsecond];

    if((dfirst == *current_depth) && (dsecond == -1)){
        vertices[vsecond] = dfirst +1;
        *current_depth = dfirst+1;
        *done = false;
    }
    if((dsecond == *current_depth) && (dfirst == -1)){
        vertices[vfirst] = dsecond + 1;
        *current_depth = dsecond +1;
        *done = false;
    }
}
```

This kernel takes values which are assigned on the host and then modified on the device and written back into the host.

So I've declared the two variables and copied them to the device in this way

```
bool h_done = true;
    bool* d_done;
    int* d_current_depth;
    int h_current_depth = 0;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_done, sizeof(bool));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_current_depth, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_done, &h_done, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_current_depth, &h_current_depth, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostDevice);
```

And launch the kernel in a loop here.

```
bfs<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(h_edges, h_vertices, d_current_depth, d_done);
```

The code compiles and runs fine but the host values never get modified on the device and vice versa. I've gone through the NVIDIA sample code in detail but can't seem to get this right. I'm new to CUDA. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should review some working CUDA samples to get a grip on it first. Typically you first copy the data from host to device, then run the computation on the device using device data and once the computations are finished you copy the device data back to host. To me it seems like you are omitting the last step.

Comment: I only need to copy the int h_current_level and a bool h_done to the device, but now that memcpy seems to be failing.

Comment: "but the host values never get modified on the device" -- they are not supposed to. You can modify host variables only in host code. Once the kernel finishes execution you have to copy the values of `d_done` and `d_current_depth` into host using `cudaMemcpy` with `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` parameter if you want to know their current value.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
bfs<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(h_edges, h_vertices, d_current_depth, d_done);
```

is almost certainly wrong.

Unless you are using managed memory (which I doubt), `h_edges` and `h_vertices` are (going by their names) variables in *host* memory. You cannot pass and modify regular host pointers in device code. Your kernel is likely failing to run because of this mistake.

The unspecified launch error your code is reporting is most likely caused by this.

Comment: That was a typo. The kernel launches fine but it's the copy that is failing. Here's the link to the complete code. I've added a printf after the kernel launch finishes and it's working fine.   https://github.com/soumasish/ParallelBreadthFirstSearch

Comment: @Antithesis: No the kernel doesn't launch fine, as you posted in your most recent question, the kernel launch is failing, and if it a was typo, it is in every one of the six versions of this code you have posted in the last 24 hours.

Comment: Well as I said, I've amended that portion and the fixed a whole slew of errors leading to the last and final problem which was there in my last question which you've closed. So any help appreciated and just as a reminder if everything worked fine there would be no need for stackoverflow anyway.

Comment: These questions aren't suitable for [SO]. This place is not a free mistake spotting/debugging  service, and **every one** of the *six* questions you have posted in the last 24 hours is nothing more than that.